# Shared R-packages in multiple Linux Distributions

Tags: r, linux, r-package

Now I have two Linux Distribution in two different partitions. I have a Data partition that is shared between them so they can use common files and folders. I have the same (major) version of R in both distributions. My question is:

- Can I use a common R-package path so that I just need to install R-packages in one and can use in other?
- What possible problems can I face in the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do.

Example the [brew](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linu) and [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) which create a directory to all bins and libs installed with those packages.

So, consider using one of them. Anyway, you might include the binaries on `ENV` using the var `PATH`.

> export PATH="my/binary/path:"$PATH

Additionally, you might prefer edit both installations `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` adding a line to edit PATH.

Particularly, I like to create a `.bashrc/` directory and include configuration files within (mypath.sh, myalias.sh, myfunctions.sh, ...) and call execution of all files with the directory just including a line on the bottom of the `.bashrc` file a line like this:

```
for file in ~/.bashrc.d/*;
do
        source $file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for packages with only R code. For packages with compiled code I do expect problems:

- Do both Linux distributions use the same linker and compiler?
- Do both Linux distributions use the same system libraries?

Comment: If not I can always install the system libraries need in that distro.